# Use of ng-ui-switch with angular 7

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to use `ng-ui-switch` but I don't have the file ui-switch.component.css in my files, with `npm install ngx-ui-switch@^1.6.0 --save` and same with `npm install ngx-ui-switch --save`...

I am using Angular 7.3.8.

I don't understand because the import in styles is `"./node_modules/ngx-ui-switch/ui-switch.component.css"` but this file doesn't exist.
I've been looking for the file only, but the only thing I find is the npm install.

Comment: is package installed successfully? able to see that package name in node modules?

Comment: Yes the package is installed successfully, there are only warns, as usual, but the directory is in node-modules and just no file has the right name

Comment: Could you tell the version which installed from package.json file

Comment: Sure, it's 1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the package and install it again without the version so it will take the latest one. You will find the css file after installing the latest one.

Commands

```
npm uninstall ngx-ui-switch --save
npm install ngx-ui-switch --save
```